# Postgres select record stored as epoch from yesterday

Tags: postgresql, date, epoch

I need to select all records from yesterday. Date in table is stored as epoch timestamp. I tried something like this, but it's not working.

```
select to_char((SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + history.clock * INTERVAL '1 second') , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS ') AS Data
from history
WHERE
history.clock >=  EXTRACT( epoch FROM current_timestamp - interval '1 day') and
history.clock <=  EXTRACT( epoch FROM current_timestamp - interval '1 day') ;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Raises an error? Incorrect result? Please edit your question with sample data and expected result.

Comment: I didnt give any resoults. Scoots Helped mi now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your problem is that you're saying "everything where clock >= 1510444800 and clock <= 1510444800". You're giving yourself a single second range.

The following query should do what you need. Increase the upper bound of the range by 86399 (There are 86400 seconds in a day, but we already have the first second of the day from our extract when combined with a `::date` cast)

```
select
    to_char(to_timestamp(history.clock), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS ') as Data
from
    history
where
    history.clock between extract(epoch from 'yesterday'::date)::integer and (extract(epoch from 'yesterday'::date)::integer + 86399)
```

I've also included a few what I consider to be improvements. No need to mess around with intervals for getting yesterday when Postgres has support for casting `'yesterday'` to a date. Comparing a value to an upper and lower bound is what the `between` keyword was made for, and there's a built in function for converting from a unix timestamp.

Comment: Thanks its what I needed :) 
I see that 
 (extract(epoch from 'today'::date)::integer -1) 
also give a last second of yesterday